# Add Header images between menu

Tags: css

I am trying to add a header image between the menu but dont know why its not showing.
I am not sure may be the reason is i put gradient color on a href thats why the header image is behind the gradient.
Can anyone help the best way to show header image between links?

```css
/** Header Menu **/

.logo_middle {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.header_menu {
  margin-top: -41px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  list-style: none;
  background: url(../icons/header_div_image.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}

.menu li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oswald', Helvetida Neue, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #ededed;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  background: #000000;
  /* Old Browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #575656, #000000);
  /*Safari 5.1-6*/
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #575656, #000000);
  /*Opera 11.1-12*/
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #575656, #000000);
  /*Fx 3.6-15*/
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #575656, #000000);
  /*Standard*/
}

.menu li a.active,
a:active,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu {
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid #f1c779;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 220px 0 #070707;
  margin: 0px 0 0 0;
  transition: .25s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.8s;
  transition: all ease 0.8s;
}

.menu h5 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.icon1 {
  height: 83px;
  background-image: url(../icons/icon1.png);
  background-position: 47px 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
}

.icon2 {
  height: 83px;
  background-image: url(../icons/icon2.png);
  background-position: 53px 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
}


/** Header Menu Close **/
```

```html
<div class="container header_menu hidden-xs hidden-sm">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/">
          <h5><span class="icon1"></span></h5>CASINO</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/slots">
          <h5><span class="icon2"></span></h5>SLOTS</a>
      </li>

    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is your image URL correct?

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj yeah Raj i have checked the image url its showing the header image

Comment: so where you want to put a background image ? to the whole `.header_menu` ?

Comment: @MihaiT i am trying to put seperator image between 2 links

Comment: i think your image path is wrong see screenshot http://prntscr.com/fkg5zn

Comment: @RajKumarBhardwaj well ofcourse here on stackoverflow his image won't work because it's on his live/local site :) not uploaded here

Comment: @MihaiT yeah you are right but i dont know how to add image path on Stakeoverflow?. is there any way i can upload somewhere image

Comment: please check answers, you should need to add your image on .menu li or .menu li a   , currently i have use border with white colors instead of image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
/** Header Menu **/

.logo_middle {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.header_menu {
  margin-top: -41px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  list-style: none;
  background: url(../icons/header_div_image.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}

.menu li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Oswald', Helvetida Neue, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #ededed;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  background: #000000;
  /* Old Browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #575656, #000000);
  /*Safari 5.1-6*/
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #575656, #000000);
  /*Opera 11.1-12*/
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #575656, #000000);
  /*Fx 3.6-15*/
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #575656, #000000);
  /*Standard*/
  border-right:3px solid #fff;
}

.menu li a.active,
a:active,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu {
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid #f1c779;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 220px 0 #070707;
  margin: 0px 0 0 0;
  transition: .25s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.8s;
  transition: all ease 0.8s;
}

.menu h5 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.icon1 {
  height: 83px;
  background-image: url(../icons/icon1.png);
  background-position: 47px 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
}

.icon2 {
  height: 83px;
  background-image: url(../icons/icon2.png);
  background-position: 53px 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
}


/** Header Menu Close **/
```

```html
<div class="container header_menu hidden-xs hidden-sm">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>
        <a href="/">
          <h5><span class="icon1"></span></h5>CASINO</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/slots">
          <h5><span class="icon2"></span></h5>SLOTS</a>
      </li>

    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

please use your image on this rule  `.menu li a {`

Comment: Thanks mate its working :) i put gradient color on .menu and looks perfectly fine :)

Comment: It's Ok dear enjoy